# Can't save file from Databricks to Azure Blob Storage Anymore

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage, databricks

My pipeline was working a few days ago, but now I can't read or write data from Databricks to the Azure store account, unless I disable the soft delete option in the storage account (we need this option to be enabled). Here's the error that I'm receiving:

org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileAlreadyExistsException: Operation failed: "This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.", 409, HEAD, https://storageaccountexample.dfs.core.windows.net/containerexample/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90

(Databricks is also running in Azure)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> Operation failed: "This endpoint does not support BlobStorageEvents or SoftDelete. Please disable these account features if you would like to use this endpoint.", 409, HEAD,https://storageaccountexample.dfs.core.windows.net/containerexample/?upn=false&action=getAccessControl&timeout=90

The above error occurs may of two possible condition :

- If you are Blob storage account is enabled with ***soft delete***  with authentication of user assigned managed identity is not supported in data flow.

[image]

- In data bricks you given linked service of source file in service type into Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2 so that also one problem kindly change into to Azure Blob Storage in the linked service.

[image]

- If you do not want to lose the soft delete, you'd need to use key authentication in the setup of the linked service.

[image]

***Reference:***
[Copy and transform data in Azure Blob storage - Azure Data Factory & Azure Synapse | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#managed-identity)